# access password protected directory

Tags: php, passwords, directory, protected

i have password protected  / public_html /images folder so that no one can see all images. But now when I am opening php page in which i need to dispaly specific iamge then i am getting login screen.. how to access password protected folder from php

Comment: How did you password-protect your files?

Comment: in hosting site, there is option..protected directories,....there i selected directory and protected...i have created user id also to access it..but dont know how to use in php to use that

Comment: PHP doesn't really have easy access to HTTP basic authentication protected directories -- it is granted or denied by the HTTP server before performing any script execution.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating two folders for images. One for public images (which you will have href's to in your php script), the other for private images which you only want access to yourself available for.

Alternatively if you want them all in the one password protected folder you need to have a PHP script on your server which will take a filename argument. Read that image off disk and then push it to the user with correct headers. Your html will have something like the following

```
<img src="image.php?name=foo.jpg">
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to prevent? Do you want to prevent someone from seeing the image filenames, but allow them to retrieve any image once they know the filename? In that case, remove read privilege for that specific directory:

```
chmod 711 /path/to/directory
```

This way, no one except the directory owner can retrieve the list of filenames from the directory, but access to the files is still allowed (the `1` is just the execute privilege for the directory, required for 'directory traversal').

Of course, you have to make sure you image file names are really unguessable, and hope that your users do not spread around the URLs (which is an easy way to bypass access controls on common sites, such as Facebook). Do decent access control checks in your program if you really want access to only authenticated users, or authorized users, or something similar.

Comment: i am not sure how to run chmod 711 /path/to/directory
...can u tell me where to run this

Comment: @subash, you run it in a shell on your web host. Typically you can use `ssh` to log in to the server to run these sorts of commands.

Comment: i got it...in file manager i can see to chnage permission.. and it works...thanks a lottttttttttttttttttttt